# Unsuccessful internal interview, should I send a thank you note to hiring manager?

Tags: interviewing

I was unsuccessful in an internal application with my company. I usually send a thank you note to the hiring manager and other interviewers afterwards but i've never been rejected for an internal move before where the hiring manager/interviewers are coworkers.

Is it still appropriate to email a thank you note to them if the role was internal?

Edit: Follow-up - is it inappropriate to ask for feedback if it was an internal role? I feel like it would be more awkward to fob me off, if so ill not ask.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Thank you letter even though I was not chosen](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/36251/thank-you-letter-even-though-i-was-not-chosen)

Comment: How was it communicated to you that your interview was unsuccessful?

Comment: @gnat No, the hiring manager and interviewers are coworkers in the same office. They sit about 20 feet from me when in the office.

Comment: @sf02 The recruiter told me via email

Answer (score 2):

A dead tree thank-you note would be overkill, but a polite reply to the original email rejecting you thanking them for their time should be fine.

> Follow-up - is it inappropriate to ask for feedback if it was an
> internal role?

It really depends on your relationship with the interviewer. No one can make that determination for you. Only you know if your relationship is good enough that you can ask that type of question. Either way, don't expect the entire truth if you do ask.